# Ubuntu 16.04 slow boot, kernel takes too long to load

Tags: boot, 16.04

When I use Ubuntu 16.04 on an SSD of my HP Probook it takes too much time to boot.

The output of `systemd-analyze` is:

```
Startup finished in 15.630s (kernel) + 7.430s (userspace) = 23.061s
```

The problem is the kernel's time which is usually faster to load, eg when I use my other hard disk with Ubuntu 16.04 on it.

I have run `dmesg` and these are the interesting parts:

```
[    0.182076] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.182082] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF97E815649C00 000119 (v01 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20130927)
[    0.183548] ACPI : EC: EC started
[    6.105620] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    6.105652] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    6.105653] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
...
[    6.287341] ACPI: Enabled 5 GPEs in block 00 to 7F
[    6.287460] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
[    6.287499] ACPI : EC: GPE = 0x6, I/O: command/status = 0x66, data = 0x62
[    6.287500] ACPI : EC: EC started
[   12.209517] SCSI subsystem initialized
[   12.209555] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[   12.209592] vgaarb: setting as boot device: PCI:0000:00:02.0
```

The kernel waits 6 seconds twice, how can I solve this?

**EDIT**

The output of `sudo fdisk -l` is

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x75916fa3

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048    2101247    2099200     1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          2101248 1798856703 1796755456 856,8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       1798858750 1953523711  154664962  73,8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1798858752 1951573595  152714844  72,8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       1951574016 1953523711    1949696   952M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 111,8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xaf997409

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 234440703 234438656 111,8G 83 Linux
```

**EDIT #2**

The `/etc/fstab` contains, ignoring the commented lines:

```
UUID=e7296fcc-53c7-42fe-b010-77aa16da72e4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Comment: This startup time seems respectable to me.  I have a fairly vanilla PC with an SSD that takes 55.680 seconds + 3.141 to boot.  I have another machine that's slightly faster than yours but the mobo is a ROG and is very fast.

Comment: @jones0610 You're right, but the strange fact is that if I use the 'slow' HDD it takes about 5 sec for the same kernel to load. Hence I think there's a problem somewhere

Comment: Possibly, although I have several PCs with HDDs that load quite fast.  Bootup speed involves a lot more than just having an SSD versus HDD.  Fast RAM (and lots of it), a fast CPU, high speed bus lanes and so on all effect how fast a machine boots.  You might be able to get a small bump in speed by running trim on the SSD since all things being equal, SSD should load faster than HDD.

Comment: Two things... have you checked for a firmware update for your SSD? Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo fdisk -l` and I'll take a look. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I've just updated the SSD firmware but nothing changed. I added the info you requested. One thing I've noticed is that when I use the low-latency kernel it takes much less time, kernel's version however is 4.8.0-58 for both the generic and the low-latency

Comment: How old is your computer? Is it UEFI? If so, why does the SSD have a msdos partition table? One partition is misaligned, but it's the extended partition, so I don't think it matters. Is your BIOS updated? Let me see your /etc/fstab.

Comment: ps: I strongly suspect that if you don't have an old BIOS, you've got a problem with the 4.8 kernel. I assume that you're running 16.04.2, yes? Try booting a Ubuntu Live DVD 17.04 and see if you see similar problems. ie:dmesg. If you must stay with 16.04, you may need to update to a newer kernel. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema No it's just 3 years. It's uefi but I find out that Ubuntu is not installed in UEFI mode. The SSD has a msdos partition probably because I took it from a Windows pc and did not change it, if this is the problem I could change the partition table. The extended partition misaligned is in the HDD so I don't think it's the problem. The BIOS is updated. I've added the fstab. Unfortunately for a project with ROS I have to keep 16.04 (.2) although when I had 17.04 the time was much shorter.

Comment: Also I tried to use the 4.10 kernel but the graphic lagged a lot. There are no newer kernels when I try `apt install linux-image` other than the 4.10

Comment: Your fstab shows no swap partition or swapfile. Any reason why not? How much RAM do you have? In reality, you should have both Windows (if you have/need it) and Ubuntu installed in the same way... that is... UEFI or not. The disk(s) then should be GPT. If you boot the Ubuntu Live DVD 17.10, do you see the same dmesg messages? Does it boot any faster... keeping in mind that you're booted to a DVD/USB?

Comment: @heynnema I've got 8GB of RAM, I didn't put the SWAP partition on my SSD for no reason, just trying if the situation could get any better. Anyway, before I switched to 16.04 I had the 17.04 and the boot time was a lot shorter

Comment: In a perfect world, I'd have you reinstall the OS's in UEFI mode, make the disks GPT, and enable swap on the HDD (and run 17.04). But I don't know if any/all of that (with the exception of 17.04) would be worth the effort in boot speed. I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks very much for your help. I'll do all these things as soon as I can